# For a lossless channel matrix, how to prove no source information is lost in transmission?

Tags: proof-writing, information-theory

For example: If the Channel matrix for Lossless Channel is
$$P(Y\mid X) = \begin{bmatrix}
0.5 & 0.5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0.25 & 0.25 & 0.5 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix},$$
then how can we prove no source information is lost in transmission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You essentially need to show that $I(X;Y)=H(X)$, i.e., that $H(X|Y)=0$. Given the matrix $P(Y|X)$ and an *arbitrary* marginal distribution $P(X)$, you can calculate the conditional probability matrix $P(X|Y)$. You will see that this matrix consists of only zeros and ones. Then, it automatically follows that $H(X|Y)=0$.